# Connect to posgresql from Jenkins and run script file

Tags: postgresql, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Have any one tried connecting to postgresql from Jenkins and trying to run the script?

I had installed **postgresql database plugin** in jenkins
And then in the **Jenkins Configuration Tool** I had tried configuring the postgresql 
When i try **Test connection** am getting an **error** as shown in the below image.

[image]

I am using a windows machine and have tried accessing the database using padmin and also tried via psql in command prompt they works fine but now connecting with jenkins am getting the following error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "223.228.174.18", user "jxxxxxxxxl", database "dxxxxxxxxx", SSL off
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:293)
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the `postgresql.conf` file and edit.

In this file, if present update or add the `'*'` for the `listen_address` like one given below

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Locate the `pg_hba.conf` file (normally found at: `pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf`) and update that as below

```
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

Restart the postgresql service like

```
service postgresql restart
```

**Note**: In a linux based OS, it will normally look like

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

or

```
service postgresql restart
```

Comment: did you try using the specific IP Address of your jenkins server, are these 2 applications in the same server or on different servers

Comment: jenkins is hosted in my local machine, postgresql is in also installed in my machine and the database is of heroku which is in a remote environmnet

Comment: you might have to check the firewall settings in the remote environment or allow your IP to access within the Heroku PaaS

Comment: Thanks @Saravanan. I was able to fix the issue by adding to parameters to the additional properties field.

So I have configured postgresql in Jenkins after installing the postgresql database plugin. Now how can I use the postgresql in my jobs. I dint find enough documentation on how can i use the stored creds inorder to run script on the remote postgresql database. Your comments on this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by adding two parameters in the Additional Properties in the Jekins Configurations for postgresql. Please find the attached image.
Fix Image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZImKs.png)